# Perfmon Resource Utilisation for PROD SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, memory

I want to create a new Data collector set to find out my Memory utilization in my PROD SQL Server for at least 2-3 weeks.

Can anyone let me know if this takes too  much resource utilization which in turn reduces Performance.

Below are the performance counters I am planning to create as adviced :

Memory – Available M Bytes

SQL Server: Buffer Manager – Page Life Expectancy (Higher is good)

SQL Server: Memory Manager – Memory Grants Pending (Lower is good)

SQL Server: Buffer Manager, Buffer Cache Hit Ratio (higher is better)

SQL Server: Memory Manager – Target Server Memory

SQL Server: Memory Manager – Total Server Memory

SQL Server: SQL Statistics – Batch Requests/sec

SQL Server: SQL Statistics – Compilations/sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfmon is pretty light weight when it comes to data collection. Collect the data in `blg` files and set a sensible collection frequency. Jonathan has written about [Essential PerfMon counters](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-accidental-dba-day-21-of-30-essential-perfmon-counters/) for DBA that will give you a good start.

For automation part you can use [`logman` and load data into sql server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1722/collecting-performance-counters-and-using-sql-server-to-analyze-the-data/) or [as shown here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2009/11/19/using-perfmon-with-sql-server-part-two/)

You can even [Setup Perfmon with PowerShell and Logman](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2012/03/02/setup-perfmon-with-powershell-and-logman.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use [PAL](https://pal.codeplex.com/) or [Get-PerfMonSummaryStats.ps1 - Powershell script from MSFT](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mhendric/2016/11/17/quickly-finding-trends-in-large-volumes-of-performance-monitor-log-files/)

`sys.dm_os_performance_counters` exposes [perfmon counters in raw form.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/09/23/interpreting-the-counter-values-from-sys-dm_os_performance_counters/)